# Hard drive full, but files / folders don't add up to used drive space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-space

My harddrive is full, but according to the size of all my folders, I should have more than half of my drive left over.

Comment: To reclaim disk space you can run `Disk Cleanup` from property window of drive. And if you are not using `hibernate` feature, you can turn it off running `powercfg -h off` command from elevated command prompt.

Comment: @Moab:  True.  However, that good post did not appear in my google search (probably because of my different wording), so I'm gonna leave this one here.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: **WinDirStat**

https://download.cnet.com/WinDirStat/3000-2248_4-10614593.html

NOTE:  When you run it, make sure to **"*Run as Administrator*"**.

Long Answer:
Unfortunately Windows Explorer (File Explorer) was dead wrong about the size of my “Program Files” folder.
It said that my “Program Files” folder was 16.5 GB.
However, inside of it I had an .LDF file that was over 200 GB!
Within about five minutes of starting WinDirStat I could see what was hogging up my drive space.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1887054-storage-does-nt-add-up-in-windows-10

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f91041e3-7e60-4193-a014-2dcf62bf1a4a/hard-drive-full-but-files-dont-add-up-to-used-drive-space?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: It will do this if you don't have administrative permissions or if show hidden files is turned off. In either case, using WinDirStat or Tree Size Free will allow you to scan these folders as administrator and get a clear picture.

Comment: @LPChip:  Thanks for the tips!  "Show hidden Files" was turned on when I searched, and I don't know any convenient way to run Windows Explorer in administrator mode.  It's amazing to me that Windows Explorer simply lies about the size of a folder, and that I have to download a third-party utility to see the truth.  Thankfully some awesome people have created said utils :-)

Comment: Thanks man, was LDF.. damn these big sql log files.. :P

Comment: @ErickBoshoff - LOL!  Yeah, they get ridic big.  Thank goodness for WinDirStat, since Windows Explorer doesn't always report accurate folder size info!