# Windows 10 storage space is incorrect

Tags: windows, hard-drive, disk-space, storage

I can't figure out what is taking up space on my hard disk, I have tried so many everything, including running disk utilities, to no avail I can't figure out what is taking up the space. If you look at my screen shots, they make no sense at all. I checked shadow storage, even have windows restore points disabled. Either way it makes no sense.

Where is the missing 30GB?

Windows 10 Storage Space

[image: Windows 10 Storage Space]

C drive:

[image: C Drive]

C drive content:

[image: C Drive Contents]

Comment: [Hard drive full, but files / folders don't add up to used drive space](https://superuser.com/q/1322886/241386), [Why don't the sizes of my folders add up to the size of my hard drive in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/304474/241386), [Windows 7 C: drive is full, but folders don't add up](https://superuser.com/q/455689/241386), [The amount of space reported by OS does not match reality](https://superuser.com/q/770986/241386), [Windows 7 disk properties dialog reports more used space than total size of files on the disk](https://superuser.com/q/524134/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't the sizes of my folders add up to the size of my hard drive in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/304474/why-dont-the-sizes-of-my-folders-add-up-to-the-size-of-my-hard-drive-in-windows)

Comment: There seems to be a bug, if you enable compression. I had this problem one year ago. Try to disable compression.

Comment: @davidbaumann compression isn't relevant here. It doesn't change the total size and only reduces the size on disk. It's not a bug, just that there are files that the user can't see or system files that didn't show

Answer (score 0):

It is likely Partitioned off as your computer manufacturers factory restore partition and likely will be hidden unless viewed with a partition manager program.

Comment: restore point with 30GB?

Comment: Not necessarily just a restore point. It will be an image of your c: drive just like it came factory. HP’s and some other manufacturers always were anywhere from 20 to 30 gig.

Answer (score 0):

It could be multiple things...

1. You have to consider that those 30GB might be taken up by your operating system and recovery partitions on your drive, let's remember that Microsoft states that the minimum storage space required for Windows 10 (64-bit) is 20GB.
2. Another possibility would be that you have a partitioned drive and there are 30GB or so of unallocated space, to check if this is the case, press the Win+R keys at the same time, the "RUN" program will open up, then type: DISKMGMT.MSC , see if there's any unallocated space of 30GB or so, it'll be easily identifiable since unallocated space is represented as a "black line", and a partition will be represented by a blue line.
3. You could have 30GB of junk files, primarily consisting of temporary files (temp files for short), although it's highly unlikely.

Hope this helps you out!